# How to use logical decoding with pg_recvlogical to pass changes through a non-trivial pipeline, and then pipe it back to a database table?

Tags: postgresql, bash, shell, pipe

I'm unable to pipe the output of PosgreSQL's `pg_recvlogical` tool through a processing command and then into a file.  When I try to do this, the target file is empty and the logical decoding events are unread.

I tried this command after first creating the slot with the default output plugin.

```bash
pg_recvlogical -d postgres --slot test --start -f - | awk '{print}' | psql
```

After inserting some data using `psql` in another terminal window, and then terminating the command above, I expected `sample.txt` to have change events.  Instead, I found it to be empty.

Weirdly, it does work when I substitute `cat` for `awk '{print}'`.

Comment: 1) This `pg_recvlogial -d postgres ..` should be `pg_recvlogical -d postgres ...` 2) Look at the example here [Logical decoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding-example.html): *Example 1: $ pg_recvlogical -d postgres --slot=test --create-slot
$ pg_recvlogical -d postgres --slot=test --start -f -* You missed the part about creating the slot.

Comment: That's a typo into StackOverflow, which I just fixed.

Comment: No, I created the slot in an earlier line that was not included.  If I omit the redirection operator (>>) and file name, it works fine and emits output.  When I include the redirection operator, or a pipe (|), it does not.

Comment: Have you tried `... -f sample.jsonl`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried `... -f sample.jsonl`.  That does write to the file, but it's not what I want.  I specifically want use `... -f -` to write to `stdout`, and then use either output redirection or, more importantly, a pipe to another command.

Comment: Sometimes `-f /dev/stdout` works when `-f -` does not. I would test that variant to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I cannot replicate using just `pg_recvlogical` and not including  the `wal2json` plugin as I don't have it installed. I'm going to say the plugin is eating the stdout.

Comment: This works as expected for me.  Maybe its an OS issue with it not flushing the file?  What is the OS?  What is the FS type where the file is?

Comment: @jjanes I believe it IS an issue with buffering.  More specifically, I actually can get it to work with file redirection.  I can get it to work if I first pipe it through cat and then redirect it into a file.  What I cannot get to work is if I pipe it through something else, like jq or even awk, and then redirect it to a file.

Comment: Try changing your awk command to `awk '{print; fflush()}'` so it prints every line as it appears and/or look into buffering options for your awk or use [`stdbuf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/133219) or similar. Disclaimer - I've no idea what `pg_recvlogical` does so I'm just guessing.

Comment: @EdMorton you're on the right track.  That works with awk, and it works with the filter I actually want to use which is jq.  In the case of jq, you use jq --unbuffered.  That's a giant clue!  Unfortunately, what I really want to do is then pipe it back to psql, but there again it fails.  FWIW, pg_recvlogical sort of does Change Data Capture (CDC) from PostgreSQL, but you can think of it just as something that emits lines of output.  In this case, I'm trying to set up a pipeline to take that output through a filter and into back into psql.

Comment: Did you try `stdbuf` or similar from [that question I linked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/133219)? That should work with any command but if it doesn't I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I suppose one alternative would be to use an intermediate file `pg_recvlogical ... | awk '{print; fflush}' > file; new_command < file`.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton.  I was hoping not to use an intermediate file.  First, because it's convenient not to use an intermediate file whenever that's possible.  Second, because I've used pipelines like this in other settings many times.  Third, and most important, because it's not just about accomplishing a task, but rather it's about upgrading my mental model to be more accurate.  Currently, I don't understand WHY I can't do this, and I would like to change that.

Comment: Right, it's just a workaround if you need it.

Comment: Actually @EdMorton it turns out `jq --unbuffered` works after all.  I don't know why it wasn't earlier.  For the record, here's the complete command:
`pg_recvlogical -d postgres -n --slot=test -o include-timestamp -o include-origin -o filter-tables=public.change_event --start -f - | jq --unbuffered -rc $'select(.change|length>0)|"insert into change_event (payload) values (\'\(.)\');"' | psql &`

Comment: @EdMorton you should get the credit since your comment about using `flush()` with `awk` was the clue I needed in order to figure out that I needed to use `jq --unbuffered`.  If you want to post the above as an answer, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @David - no, I just guessed at a suggestion of something to try, you should post your the answer from your comment and then accept it so others can find it in future. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple recipe for using [logical decoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding.html) to capture change events using the [wal2json](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json) output plugin, passing them through a non-trivial `jq` filter, and then storing them back in the database, in a `change_event` table which is not itself included in change capture.  It may be adapted to suit other needs.

```bash
psql -d postgres -c "create unlogged table change_event (payload jsonb)"
pg_recvlogical -d postgres --slot=test --create-slot -P wal2json
pg_recvlogical -d postgres -n --slot=test -o filter-tables=public.change_event --start -f - | jq --unbuffered -rc $'select(.change|length>0)|"insert into change_event (payload) values (\'\(.)\');"' | psql -d postgres &
```

Here's how this works.

1. The unlogged `change_event` table is an created with a `jsonb` data type since we're using `wal2json`.
2. `pg_recvlogical` creates a slot with the `wal2json` output plugin.
3. `pg_recvlogical` captures events withut restart (`-n`).
4. An option to `filter-tables` helps avoid circular events involving the `change_event` table (note that this isn't strictly necessary since `change_event` is `unlogged` but it's an extra precaution).
5. The data are emitted to `stdout` (-f -)
6. They're passed through `jq`, crucially with the `--unbuffered` switch. The `-r` and `-c` switches are also useful here.
7. The `jq` filter removes events with an empty change set (`select(.change|length>0)`).
8. They're fed into a string template to generate a SQL `insert` statement.
9. The output is piped to `psql` in order to write to the `change_event` table in the database.

Comment: The stumbling block here was the buffering that `jq` does.  The comments from Ed Morton regarding `awk` and its buffering, and the use of `flush()`, was the major clue I needed in order to investigate any buffering that `jq` does, which led me to discover its `--unbuffered` switch.